# Windows Function with Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say we have this table. The examinees have to retake the exams sporadically to show their progress. The examinees have to retake the exams in a given window starting from the `exam_date`. In order for it to be considered a `Month_1`, the examinees need to take the exam after `26` days to `34` days of the initial `exam_date`. For `Month_2`, the examinees need to take the exam after `54` days to `64` days of the initial `exam_date`.

```
Select * from my_table

examinee    exam_date   retake_date       site        
Danny       3/2/2020    3/30/2020        NYC             
Steve       4/4/2020    5/24/2020        London          
Eddie       4/26/2020   5/31/2020        Los Angeles     
Eddie       4/26/2020   6/27/2020        NYC             
Steve       4/4/2020    6/3/2020         London          
Danny       3/2/2020    5/1/2020         Los Angeles
```

My Attempt:

```
case when first_value(exam_date + interval '26 days') over (partition by examinee)::date 
and first_value(exam_date + interval '34 days') over (partition by examinee)::date then 'Month_1'
when first_value(exam_date + interval '56 days') over (partition by examinee)::date 
and  first_value(exam_date + interval '64 days') over (partition by examinee)::date then 'Month_2'  
else 'Missed' end as month_number
```

Error:

```
argument of AND must be type boolean, not type date
```

Requested:

```
examinee    exam_date   retake_date       site         month_number
Danny       3/2/2020    3/30/2020        NYC             Month_1
Steve       4/4/2020    5/24/2020        London          Missed
Eddie       4/26/2020   5/31/2020        Los Angeles     Month_1
Eddie       4/26/2020   6/27/2020        NYC             Month_2
Steve       4/4/2020    6/3/2020         London          Month_2
Danny       3/2/2020    5/1/2020         Los Angeles     Month_2
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really need to use `first_value` function? In the requested result set, it seems that all calculation is row based.

Answer (score 0):

Because of `exam_date` same for an examinee, i think we do not need to use `first_value` function.

```
select *,
case 
when retake_date - exam_date > 26 and retake_date - exam_date < 34 then 'Month_1'
when retake_date - exam_date > 56 and retake_date - exam_date < 64 then 'Month_2'  
else 'Missed' end as month_number,
retake_date - exam_date as day_between -- to debug
FROM my_table
```